# Cannot pan to correct location using IEnvelope.CenterAt(IPoint)

Tags: arcobjects, c#, add-in

It seems no matter what projection I try it pans me to the Atlantic Ocean. I have run across this before in an ArcPy script and it was due to being in a projected coordinate system and thus it was reading the coordinates as x meters away from the origin, but to my understanding a geographic coordinate system would read them differently. Whenever I use GoToXY with these coordinates it puts me in Texas. (10.1 SP1, C#.NET, VS2010, Desktop Addin)

```
IMxDocument mxdoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
IEnvelope pEnv = mxdoc.ActiveView.Extent;
ISpatialReferenceFactory srFactory = new SpatialReferenceEnvironmentClass();
int gcsCode = (int)esriSRGeoCSType.esriSRGeoCS_WGS1984;
ISpatialReference spatRef = srFactory.CreateGeographicCoordinateSystem(gcsCode);

try
{
    IPoint point = new PointClass();
    double xCoord = 33.217918;
    double yCoord = -98.158749;
    point.SpatialReference = spatRef;
    point.PutCoords(xCoord, yCoord);

    pEnv.CenterAt(point);
    mxdoc.ActiveView.Extent = pEnv;
    mxdoc.ActiveView.Refresh();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Swap xCoord and yCoord. X = longitude, Y = latitude in Esri software.

Comment: I had suspected that as well but when I switched them it took me to the same place (which is also odd).

Comment: What coordinate system is the data data frame using? Or maybe set pEnv to have the same spatial reference?

Comment: The data frame projection was a type of WGS84 so I assumed it was geographic but it was actually projected, if it's changed to a GCS the pan works. Thanks!